# The script sqlformat.exe is installed in directory , which is not on PATH

Tags: python, django, path, pycharm, virtualenv

I am getting this warning while I was trying to install django in a virtual environment in pycharm. But while I open python in command prompt then I don't get any warning like 'python is not in path or something', then why am I getting this warning now in pycharm? pls help me fix this, thankyou in advance.

Answer (score -2):

The complete directory can be added to path by:

1. Right-clicking "This PC" and going to "Properties".
2. Clicking on the "Advanced system settings" present under "Related Settings".
3. Clicking on the "Environment Variables" button on the bottom right.
4. In the "System variables" section, selecting the "Path" variable and clicking on "Edit". (The next screen will show all the directories that are currently a part of the PATH variable.)
5. Clicking on "New" and entering path of directory which is supposedly said to be missing from the warning message you got.
6. Restart the code editor for the changes you made to the system to apply.